# números aleatorios en parejas en c++

Tags: c++

Necesito crear un programa que me cree un cuadro con números aleatorios pero que cada número tenga su pareja, pero el problema es que soy nueva en esto de la programación y necesito resolverlo con algo básico.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int srand (time(NULL));//es un comando que me permite generar # random sin que se repitan.
    int aleatorio;
    int const num=1;
    int tamano[num];


    cout<<"Dimencion del cuadro:"<<endl;
    cin>>tamano[num];

    for(int i=0; i<tamano[num]; i++){
      for(int j=1;j<tamano[num]; j++){

        aleatorio=1+rand()%(10-1);
        cout<<aleatorio<<" ";
      }
      aleatorio=1+rand()%(10-1);
      cout<<alea
          aleatorio<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```